# Setup HttpContext.GetOpenIddictServerRequest() for Controller Unit Test

Tags: asp.net-core, moq, mstest, httpcontext

I am using MS Tests to write Unit tests for controller that authorizes the user using OAuth. I understand it is not a great idea to Moq HttpContext. Can I get help with setting up GetOpenIddictServerRequest().
The Controller End point is

````
 public async Task<IActionResult> Authorize()
        {
            var request = HttpContext.GetOpenIddictServerRequest() ??
                throw new InvalidOperationException("The OpenID Connect request cannot be retrieved.");

            // If prompt=login was specified by the client application,
            // immediately return the user agent to the login page.
            if (request.HasPrompt(Prompts.Login))
            {
                // To avoid endless login -> authorization redirects, the prompt=login flag
                // is removed from the authorization request payload before redirecting the user.
                var prompt = string.Join(" ", request.GetPrompts().Remove(Prompts.Login));

                var parameters = Request.HasFormContentType ?
                    Request.Form.Where(parameter => parameter.Key != Parameters.Prompt).ToList() :
                    Request.Query.Where(parameter => parameter.Key != Parameters.Prompt).ToList();

                parameters.Add(KeyValuePair.Create(Parameters.Prompt, new StringValues(prompt)));

                return Challenge(
                    authenticationSchemes: IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme,
                    properties: new AuthenticationProperties
                    {
                        RedirectUri = Request.PathBase + Request.Path + QueryString.Create(parameters)
                    });
            }
```
````

The code Snipped looks like

```
public static OpenIddictRequest? GetOpenIddictServerRequest(this HttpContext context)
        {
            if (context == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
            }

            return context.Features.Get<OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreFeature>()?.Transaction?.Request;
        }
```

I tried setting up HttpContext in my TestMethod as:

```
 _authorizationController.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext() { HttpContext = new DefaultHttpContext() {   } };
```